# Changing row of equation in different position in latex

Tags: equations

Firstable, this is what I want:

[image]

As you can see, there are total 3 rows in equation : the first row change and second row change occurred in different positions. I tried to make like that with :

```
\begin{align}
    S & =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dt(\cdots) \nonumber \\
    & = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dE}{2\pi}[((1 && +i\epsilon)E^2-(1-i\epsilon)\omega^2)\tilde{q}(E)\tilde{q}(-E) \nonumber \\
    && + \tilde{f}(E)\tilde{q}(-E)+\tilde{f}(-E)\tilde{q}(E)
\end{align}
```

But the result was quite strange(the second row of the equation was separated).
So my question is, how can I make such an equation like that with LaTeX?

Comment: Wrap the `[( ..]` part in a `\begin{aligned}[t] [(....] \end{aligned}` and use approriate `&` alignments and line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `\IEEEeqnarray*` environment from the [`IEEEtrantools`](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) package. Here you can specify the columns in a similar way to the `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rClcl}
    S & = & \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dt(\cdots) & &  \\
      & = & \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dE}{2\pi}\bigl[\bigl((1 & {} + {} & i\epsilon)E^2-(1-i\epsilon)\omega^2\bigr)\tilde{q}(E)\tilde{q}(-E) \\
      &   &                                                                   & {} + {} & \tilde{f}(E)\tilde{q}(-E)+\tilde{f}(-E)\tilde{q}(E)\bigr] \IEEEyesnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[Here](https://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf) is a link to a tutorial on this environment.

Answer (score 2):

How about this layout with the `\multlined` environment from `mathtools`, and various improvements as to the size of delimiters?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align}
        S & =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dt(\cdots) \nonumber \\
        & = \begin{multlined}[t]\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dE}{2\pi}\Bigl[\bigl((1 +i\epsilon)E^2-(1-i\epsilon)\omega^2\bigr)\tilde{q}(E)\tilde{q}(-E) \nonumber \\[-2ex]
         + \tilde{f}(E)\tilde{q}(-E)+\tilde{f}(-E)\tilde{q}(E)\Bigr]
    \end{multlined}
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `alignat{n}`

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  S &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dt(\cdots) \nonumber \\
    &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dE}{2\pi}
      \Bigl[\Bigl((1 &&+ i\epsilon) E^2 - (1 - i\epsilon)\omega^2 \Bigr) \tilde{q}(E)\tilde{q}(-E) \nonumber \\
    &                &&+ \tilde{f}(E)\tilde{q}(-E)+\tilde{f}(-E)\tilde{q}(E)\Bigr].
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```